# coffescript custom folding

Tags: vim, macvim

For "standard" JavaScript, I have this custom folding function which I like a lot:

```
function! JavaScriptFold()
    setl foldmethod=syntax
    setl foldlevelstart=1
    set fillchars=fold:\ 
    syn region foldBraces start=/{/ end=/}/ transparent fold keepend extend

    function! FoldText()
        return substitute(getline(v:foldstart), '{.*', '{...}', '')
    endfunction
    setl foldtext=FoldText()
endfunction
```

Could a kind soul please show me a translation of this for CoffeeScript?
So that

```
testFunction = (x) ->
    x + x
```

would be folded like this into its first line only

```
testFunction = (x) ->
```

Bonus points for folding literal objects too, but functions would be great already!

PS: of course, I'm using the coffee-script plugin for Vim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I don't know cofee, and I don't know what literal objects it support, I can't help with that. However what you want, can be achieved by this setting (which could be translated into a modeline):

```
:setl fdm=expr fde=getline(v:lnum)=~'->$'?'>1':getline(v:lnum)=~'^\\s*$'?0:'='
```

You didn't specify what to display on the fold, so I left this out. You can use the foldtext setting for that. See `:h fold-foldtext` for that.

Comment: Hi Christian, thanks a lot for your answer.  It works great but has one problem: when several functions (->) are nested inside an outer function, the inner functions fold their contents but are not themselves folded (hidden) by the outer function ?

Comment: I think this should work:`:setl fdm=expr fde=getline(v:lnum)=~'->$'&&indent(v:lnum)<indent(v:lnum+1)?'a1':'s1'`

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks a lot Christian, really appreciate.

Comment: Christian, would you mind explaining exactly how that works? Thanks!

Comment: If I remember correctly, this means, that all lines that end with '->' start a fold of level 1, all lines that contain only spaces are not folded and all other lines, inherit the foldlevel from the previous line.